# How to make menu and toolbar in extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm new in Extjs. I would like to know. Which components I can use, to make a menu and toolbar like in desktop app? 
I mean something like this.[image]

I wrote this code, but the result is not similar to desktop app menu.

```
Ext.define('untitled.view.main.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
xtype: 'app-main',

width: 200,
height: 150,
tbar: [{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Select',
    menu:   Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
        items: [{
            text: 'JavaScript',
            handler: function () {
                alert('Selected JavaScript');
            }
        }, {
            text: 'Java',
        }, {
            text: 'C/C++'
        }]
    })
}]
```

});

New -------

[image]

Thank you very much, and the last question. How can I remove this arrow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is fiddle for you - [desktop-like toolbar](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12d9) (use your `iconCls` for *Icon* buttons).

Ask if you need something updated.

Comment: Thank you very much, and the last question. How can I remove this arrow?

Comment: Remove arrow class with `arrowCls: ''` property. Fiddle updated.